# Flutter get key - Json

Tags: json, object, flutter, dart

How can I get the text of inside the key?

I am able to use keys Using **keys** like this ..

```
print(myData[0]["1"].keys);
```

output: (a, b, c, d)

JSON File looks like this:

```
 [
       {
           "1":{
             "a": "text",
             "b": "text",
             "c": "text",
             "d": "text"
           }
        }
   ]
```

I was able to get first key name using.. keys.first
But I also want to get other keys name but when I use keys.second or keys.third that doesn't work. how else I can get key's text/name?       thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`keys` is an `iterable`, so you can convert it to a `List` an access each key by its index:

```
//Will print 'd'
print(json[0]["1"].keys.toList()[3]);
```

or iterate over each one:

```
//Will print all the keys (a b c d)
json[0]["1"].keys.forEach((key){ print(key); });
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer...json[0]["1"].keys.toList()[3] worked.